# React mouseX position is incorrect

Tags: reactjs, position

I have a problem with x coordinates of mouse position. I have a relative div on whose mousemove I want to get x and y coordinates of mouse and show tooltip with these positions. Tooltip has absolute positioning. Whereas top is perfectly fine, left/right is always far away from mouse.

Example: `<https://codepen.io/rosy654/pen/PoNZENN>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah I found a solution, instaed of e.x i used e.offsetX and it works